# Transfer files between 2 iPhones over wifi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

I've spent a few days looking for different solutions, but the whole area is quite complicated, and I'm wondering if anybody knows of any project where I can simply transfer NSData or an NSString or some other simple file over wifi to another iPhone on the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Np. Use bonjour to search for devices. Then use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to send and receive data. It works like a charm.

Little info about AsyncSock:

> GCDAsyncSocket and AsyncSocket are TCP/IP socket networking libraries.
>   Here are the key features available in both:
>
> Native objective-c, fully self-contained in one class. No need to muck
>   around with sockets or streams. This class handles everything for you.
>
> Full delegate support Errors, connections, read completions, write
>   completions, progress, and disconnections all result in a call to your
>   delegate method.
>
> Queued non-blocking reads and writes, with optional timeouts. You tell
>   it what to read or write, and it handles everything for you. Queueing,
>   buffering, and searching for termination sequences within the stream -
>   all handled for you automatically.
>
> Automatic socket acceptance. Spin up a server socket, tell it to
>   accept connections, and it will call you with new instances of itself
>   for each connection.
>
> Support for TCP streams over IPv4 and IPv6. Automatically connect to
>   IPv4 or IPv6 hosts. Automatically accept incoming connections over
>   both IPv4 and IPv6 with a single instance of this class. No more
>   worrying about multiple sockets.
>
> Support for TLS / SSL Secure your socket with ease using just a single
>   method call. Available for both client and server sockets.