# Simple way of sending a message to a client connected over a network?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transfer files between 2 iPhones over wifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637598/transfer-files-between-2-iphones-over-wifi)

I already have my device connected to another device over wifi, now what i need to do is to be able to send data between them. I followed a tutorial here:

http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxix-message

Which got complicated and errorsome as soon as i imported the open source 'AsyncSocket'.

There must be a simple way to do it, just to use the network which I already have set up from a server to a client, to send a message across?

I'm using NSNetService and NSNetServiceBrowser. I hope somebody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using HTTP as a message protocol.

You get the benefit of being able to simulate messages using a web browser or a [client tool](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/), and [HTTP Scoop](http://tuffcode.com) is an excellent debugging tool.

The client-side code is all ready in NSURLConnection, and there are a few open source HTTP servers that are ready to integrate into your app. I'd recommend [Matt Gallagher's implementation](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html), I've used it very successfully to do exactly what you're describing.